# Convert result from one column to 2 rows and more

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Is it possible to take from one column the result and transfer it to two columns.
By taking the first and second results as start and end
and everyone else in the same way.
i used pivot but didn't get any real result.

current  result

```
 rn old_date_row 

 1   01-JUN-18
 2   null 
 3   null 
 4   null
 5   22-JUN-18
 6   null
 7   null
 8   null
 9   25-JUN-19
 10  null
 11  null
 12  25-JUN-20
```

expected result
new table

```
    start_date      end_date
   01-JUN-18       22-JUN-18    
   25-JUN-19       25-JUN-20
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using, also share what have you tried so far

Comment: What if we add another row ( exemple `13  26-JUN-20`) ?

Comment: Dates are expected to always be 2s or 4s or 6s and so on.  I used pivot but didn't get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enumerate rows that are not null using `row_number()` then identify successive rows using `round(rid/2)` :

```
select old_date_row, rid, round(rid/2)
from (
  select old_date_row, row_number() over (order by rn) rid
  from mytable t
  where old_date_row is not null
)
```

Results :

```
OLD_DATE_ROW    RID ROUND(RID/2)
01-06-18        1   1
22-06-18        2   1
25-06-19        3   2
25-06-20        4   2
```

The final query can be :

```
select min(old_date_row) as start_date, max(old_date_row) as end_date
from (
  select old_date_row, row_number() over (order by rn) rid
  from mytable t
  where old_date_row is not null
)
group by round(rid/2);
```

Results :

```
START_DATE  END_DATE
01-06-18    22-06-18
25-06-19    25-06-20
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/q5qPs8xn)